# Pyinstaller exectuable using data from other folders?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I've written a program that generates a random name and displays a random image along with it using Python and tkinter. However, I want the user to be able to add and remove pictures as well as edit the names of students. That being said, I don't want to package these inside the executable where it can't be changed by the user.

To use PyInstaller, I go into the command prompt and navigate to the working directory and type:

```
pyi-makespec --windowed --onefile --icon=Assets\\icon.ico random_student.py
```

Then, in the spec file I change datas to:

```
datas=[('Assets\\icon.ico', 'Assets')],
```

Then, I run

```
pyinstaller random_student.spec
```

The program runs just fine using PyCharm. And I've done this exact same method on a couple of other .py files an it works. However, they don't need to pull images/text into their programs. This will create an executable, but I can't run it. It gives me a Fatal Error "Failed to execute script random_student". I've tried placing the executable in the working directory and in the pictures folder, but neither work.

I'm currently using Windows 10 64-bit and Python 3.6.6

I'd appreciate any kind of help I can get with this!

SOLUTION: I removed the --windowed option so I could actually read the error. Then realized I didn't have Pillow installed so it was unable to be packaged. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Could you please remove the `--windowed` argument in the pyinstaller command? This will allow you to see the console output. However the console may open and close really quickly. In this case I suggest to open cmd, `cd` to the directory with your exe and the running the exe. This will prevent the output to be hidden for us.

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought of that...

C:\Users\tomal\Desktop\Programs\random_student>random_student.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "random_student.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
[6716] Failed to execute script random_student

So it seems for some reason PIL isn't being loaded up. Any ideas on how to fix that? I haven't tried any other scrips that use PIL.

Comment: Add `'PIL'` (maybe `'Pillow'`) to `hidden_imports` in the spec file.

Comment: Maybe you could include the spec file in your question also.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please edit your original post to add the text requested in the comment.  Also, please avoid posting to external images, which when deleted, will render this post meaningless.  The point of SO is to create a lasting encyclopedia of questions and answers, and to help people later who have similar issues.  Thanks!

Comment: I got it working! I'm so sorry guys, it was such an easy solution. I forget I reinstalled Python the other night and forgot to install pillow again. Since I usually run my scripts from PyCharm I had it installed there, but not outside of the PyCharm directory. Thank you so much. I at least learned the tip about NOT using --windowed to see what's actually occuring.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information on what makes a great post.